# Does sizeof result depends on the declaration of the string?

Tags: arrays, c, char, sizeof, string-literals

I get the size of str character array with the following test code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char str[] = "abcde";
    for(int j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        printf("str[%u]=%c;  %i\n", j, *(str+j), *(str+j));
    }
    printf("sizeof(str)=%lu\nstrlen(str)=%lu\n", sizeof(str), strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
```

The result is 6, as expected, as can be seen in the screen output here below:

```
str[0]=a;  97
str[1]=b;  98
str[2]=c;  99
str[3]=d;  100
str[4]=e;  101
str[5]=;  0
str[6]=;  0
sizeof(str)=6    //here it is!
strlen(str)=5
```

However, if I explicitly include the string dimension (5) in its declaration, like this:

```
unsigned char str[5] = "abcde";
```

now the result of sizeof is 5 rather than the expected 6, as can be seen from the function output:

```
str[0]=a;  97
str[1]=b;  98
str[2]=c;  99
str[3]=d;  100
str[4]=e;  101
str[5]=;  0
str[6];  8
sizeof(str)=5    // why 5 and not 6???
strlen(str)=5
```

My question: what is the reason for that different result?
Note the termination character is correctly placed after last string character, as can be seen from the examples above.
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: In the first program, your array have six elements. You print seven. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: This buffer is insufficient in size and `strlen()` on that is undefined behaviour. You got lucky because the next byte is likely 0, but in a non-trivial program this could easily crash.

Comment: With `str[] = "abcde"` size is calculated by compiler: 5 characters + null terninator. With `str[5] = "abcde"` you set size explicitly. No null terminator included.

Comment: And in C, when you don't allow space for the null-terminator it will not be added. In the case of `unsigned char str[5] = "abcde";` you don't have a proper null-terminated string. Passing it to `strlen` will also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also note that both the `sizeof` operator and the `strlen` function returns a value of type `size_t`. To print a `size_t` value with `printf` you must use the `%zu` format specifier. Mismatching argument type and format specifier *also* leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: On a totally different note, for any array of pointer `str` and index `j`, the expression `*(str + j)` is *exactly* equal to `str[j]`. Please use the latter, array indexing syntax, as it's usually easier to read and understand at a quick flance.

Comment: `j <= 6` makes the program have undefined behavior in both cases since you dereference `str[6]` which is out of bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string literal `"abcde"` used as an initializer of the array `str` has `6` characters including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

But you explicitly declared the array only with `5` characters:

```
unsigned char str[5] = "abcde";
              ^^^^^^
```

So it is even unimportant how you are initializing the array because you explicitly specfied its size equal to `5` and `sizeof( unsigned char )` is always equal to `1`. So `sizeof( str )` is evidently equal to `5`.

Pay attention to that in this case your array does not contain a string because it is unable to accommodate the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal. So for eample calling the function `strlen` for the array invokes undefined behavior.

Opposite to `C` in `C++` such a declaration is invalid. In `C++` you should write at least

```
unsigned char str[6] = "abcde";
```

or as you wrote the first declaration of the array like

```
unsigned char str[] = "abcde";
```

In the last case the number of elements in the array is equal to the number of characters in the string literal.

Also to output values of the type `size_t` you should use conversion specifier `zu` instead of `lu` because in general it is not necessay that the type `size_t` is an alias of the type `unsigned long`. In some systems it can be an alias of the type `unsigned long long`.

Frpm the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>)

> Recommended practice
>
> 4 The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int **unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary**.

So you need to write

```
printf("sizeof(str)=%zu\nstrlen(str)=%zu\n", sizeof(str), strlen(str));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that I have accepted. Nevertheless, considering the case with declaration/definition unsigned char str[5] = "abcde" it is very surprising (for me) that the program output a zero (\0) seems to be placed in the array 6th element, i.e. str[5]='\0', as if the compiler understands that it has to be there...

Comment: @Guille `str[5]` is outside the array and the access results in UB. You just got lucky!

Comment: @Vlad There is more: if initialize the string as unsigned char str[5] = "abcde", the compiler gives me no warning and ta zero IS PLACED in 6th elemnt str[5]. If I change 5 by 4 by defining unsigned char str[4] = "abcde" then the compiler gives me a warning. However, also in this case the \0 terminator IS PLACED in the 4th array elent str[4]. Very strange...

Comment: @Ian Sorry, it can't be just luck. I have tested it tens of times, the fifth element is ALWAYS zero and the following ones have, as one could expect, random values. But not the fifth one, as I said, it is always zero.

Comment: @Guille It is undefined behavior. It just occured such a way that after the last element of the array the memory is zero initialized. But in general it is just an accident. The array has only 5 elements as it is declared. It can not be automatically enlarged.

Comment: @Guille Just place before and after the array other two variables as for example char s1[2] = "12";  char str[5] = "abcde"; char s2[2] = "34"; and check your program. For example output the value of strlen( str );

Answer (score 2):

`strlen(str)` in the second case is an undefined behavior.

> Note the termination character is correctly placed after last string character, as can be seen from the examples above.

No, it's not. As per C11 6.7.9 14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
> literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
> terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
> elements of the array.

There's no room for the terminating null character, so it's not added. Thus the result of `sizeof` is different.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment. So it meas that the \0 character that I can see in the 6th array element str[5] was there by chance and not placed there by the compiler, correct? (I am referring to the case with the declaration unsigned char str[5] = "abcde";

Comment: @Guille Yes, there is no room in the array to store the terminating zero character. The first character of the string literal initializes the first element of the array. The second character of the string literal initializes the second element of the array and so on. But for the sixth element of the string literal there is no corresponding free element of the array.